# Removing element created dynamically with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a element and text with jQuery to overlay another element:

```
$("<div></div>").text("winner")
                .css( {position:"absolute", top:"48%", left:"40%", zIndex:9999} )
                .appendTo( $(".square2").css({position:"relative"}) )
```

Afterwards I need to remove it, so I checked the position of the element in Chrome:

```
<div class="square2">
   <p>Something</p>
   <p>Something</p>
   <table></table>
   <div>winner</div>
</div>
```

And finally I tried to remove selecting it as last child:

```
$("div.square:last-child").remove();
```

But it removes all the children of div.square, not only the last one.(???)

Comment: do you need to remove last dynamically appended div

Answer (score 1):

You can use it:

```
var el = $("<div></div>").text("winner")
                    .css({
                            position:"absolute",
                            top:"48%",
                            left:"40%",
                            zIndex:9999,
                    });
    el.appendTo($(".square2").css({position:"relative"}));
    el.remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

To  remove the last div inside `.square` you could use :

```
$("div.square div:last-child").remove();
```

Hope his helps.

```js
$("div.square div:last-child").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="square">
   <p>Something</p>
   <p>Something</p>
   <table></table>
   <div>winner1</div>
   <div>winner2</div>
   <div>winner3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have chosen this.it was easier than thought.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("<div>winner1</div>")
                  .css({
                          position:"absolute",
                          top:"48%",
                          left:"40%",
                          zIndex:9999,
                        }).appendTo($(".square2").css({position:"relative"}));

    /*binding the rmeove on click of button. Can change it according to your needs.*/
    $("#remove").click(function(){
      $('.square2 div:last-child').remove();
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square2">
     <p>Something</p>
     <p>Something</p>
     <table></table>
   <div>winner</div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="remove">Remove</button>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with a pure jQuery answer, you could use the following:

```
$('.square').children().filter('div').last().remove()
```

This will take the element(s) with class `square`, select all it's(or their) children, filter so only the `div` elements are still selected, narrow that down by only selecting the last element in that list, and then finally remove that element.  Hope this is what you were looking for.